# use data as an object in $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

im trying to pass different parameters to data converting as an object, but im new in this and i need some help, this is my code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://....org/api/get_category_posts',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            //data:'category_name=rock&count=2&order=desc',
            data: { 

                dataRock:'category_name=rock&count=2&order=desc', 
                dataPop:'category_name=pop&count=2&order=desc', 
                dataElectronica:'category_name=electronica&count=2&order=desc' 
            },

            success: function(data) {

                var albumsRock = function()
                {  

                    $('albumsRock').html(''); // vaciamos previamente el html

                    for(var i=0; i < data[dataRock].posts.length; i++)
                    {
                        addAlbum(data[dataRock].posts[i]);
                    }

                }
```

there are 3 parameters and i dont know how to access them, thanks!!

Comment: Do you want: `data["dataRock"].posts` or is dataRock actually a variable?

Comment: no, dataRock is one data parameter and i don't know how to access to one of this parameters, this, data[dataRock].posts, i think is incorrect

Comment: So you have `var dataRock = "XXXXX";` defined somewhere?

Comment: no, just i want to know how to access to data parameters, data: { 

                dataRock:'category_name=rock&count=2&order=desc', 
                dataPop:'category_name=pop&count=2&order=desc', 
                dataElectronica:'category_name=electronica&count=2&order=desc' 
            }, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

data being passed in has NOTHING to do with the data being sent back from the server. Your variable names are the same, that is about it. If you want to know what was sent up, use a local variable to hold the data.

```
var requestData = { 
    dataRock:'category_name=rock&count=2&order=desc', 
    dataPop:'category_name=pop&count=2&order=desc', 
    dataElectronica:'category_name=electronica&count=2&order=desc' 
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://....org/api/get_category_posts',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: requestData,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(requestData.dataRock);
    }
});
```

In your code, you have

```
data[dataRock].posts.length
```

I am assuming you want to use dataRock as a key since dataRock in the above is not an object

```
 data[requestData.dataRock].posts.length
```

Comment: thanks!!! that was the idea, i wasn't be able to find the solution, thank you very much!!

Comment: i'm back, when i have tried to implement this changes show me this error: TypeError: data[requestData.dataRock] is undefined
 for(var i=0; i < data[requestData.dataRock].posts.length; i++), i made everything that you said and i did some changes but nothing, thanks in advance!

Comment: Well than data does not have it. What in the world does your response look like?

Comment: this is how i implement your idea: {  

                        $('albumsRock').html(''); // vaciamos previamente el html

                        for(var i=0; i < data[requestData.dataRock].posts.length; i++)
                        {
                            addAlbum(data[requestData.dataRock].posts[i]);
                        }
                        
                    }

Comment: What is the response back from the server?!

Comment: console.log says **is undefined**